# Using web dojo and assign local package

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo in my local application. The dojo.js is uploaded on some website.

I have some packages which are in my local application.

How can I specify the location of these local packages in dojoConfig of this web dojo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CDN tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/cdn/) explains how to define additional packages when using a remote-hosted version of Dojo.  You would define local `packages` in your `dojoConfig`, something like the following:

```
packages: [ {
    name: 'custom',
    location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '/js/custom')
} ]
```

(This would make the loader load any modules in the `custom` package from the `js/custom` directory under the same directory as the page being viewed.)